# Javascript setInterval: multiple intervals

Tags: javascript, canvas, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm playing with  animations. I'm trying to have two circles move a specified distance and then stop. The issue I'm having is with multiple intervals. I assign each interval to a unique variable, and clearInterval that variable, but the first interval continues on.

Here is the code:

```
function moveRight(player){

if(player==1){
    currentLoc = p1Loc[0];            //global var with player's current location
    intervalR1 = setInterval(function(){
        p1Loc[0]+=1;
        draw();                      //function that redraws the canvas
        if(p1Loc[0]>currentLoc+wu){  //wu is a single "width-unit"
            clearInterval(intervalR1);
        }
    },5)
}
else{
    currentLoc = p2Loc[0];
    intervalR2 = setInterval(function(){
        p2Loc[0]+=1;
        draw();
        if(p2Loc[0]>currentLoc+wu){
            clearInterval(intervalR2);
        }
    },5)
}

}
```

Then, let's say I give the following instructions within a while loop:

```
instructions = ["moveRight(1)", "moveRight(2)"];
for(instruction in instructions){
    eval(instructions[instruction]); //I know, eval(), ugh. Is just temporary
}
```

What ends up happening is, both players start moving right, but player 2 stops after a single wu, or width-unit while player one keeps going. If i change the instructions to only "moveRight(1);", then player one moves a single wu and stops.

What's going on here?

Comment: Just FYI, consider using [requestAnimationFrame](http://davidwalsh.name/requestanimationframe-shim) instead of playing with intervals.

Comment: It may be that intervalR? is not set until after the setInterval completes. This would be easy enough to test by placing an alert before the clearInterval call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, since is a bit hard to tell what is going on with only part of the code, but could it be that you are assigning `currnetLoc` twice, and thus the first player's location will always be always be compared against `p2Loc[0]`?

So when you call `moveRight(1)` it sets `currentLoc` to `p1Loc[0]` then proceeds. Then immediately after you call `moveRight(2)` which sets `currentLoc` to `p2Loc[0]`. So now the comparison for the interval for player 1 is no longer `p1Loc[0]>currentLoc+wu`, but rather `p2Loc[0]>currentLoc+wu`. Depending on the value of `p2Loc` this may always be `false`.

Comment: Yes! Good catch. Will mark correct in 6 min (per SO rules)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
currentLoc = p1Loc[0];            //global var with player's current location
```

is kinda scary. Don't use a global for this, especially when you re-assign its value on the second entry to the function:

```
currentLoc = p2Loc[0];
```

That's likely your problem.

If you need to keep track of a single player's position, create a player object and keep track of it in there, something like:

```
function Player(number) {
    this.number = number
    this.position = 0 //some default initial position
}
```

and pass this into moveRight()

Comment: You also identified the problem. isomarcte was first, but you are absolutely right about the global vars. I'm absolutely throwing good code principles to the wind currently as I'm just hacking something together to learn about canvas animation. I guess this is what happens when you do that... Thanks!